# How can I create new instances of different classes in a good way?

Tags: php, object

I have a class, more specific a repository. This repository will hold my validators so I can reach them whenever I want. Currently it looks like this:

```
class ValidatorRepository {
     private $validators; 

     public function __construct() {
          $this->validators = array();
     }

     public function get($key) {
          return $this->validators[$key];
     }

     public function add($key, iValidator $value) {
          $this->validators[$key] = $value;
     }
     public static function getInstance() {
           //(...)
     }
}
```

And with this class I would like to do something like this:

```
$vr = ValidatorRepository::getInstance(); 
$vr->add("string", new StringValidator());
```

I can insert something else than a instantiated object if that is for the better.

.. and later on, somewhere else;

```
$vr = ValidatorRepository::getInstance(); 
$vr->get("string"); // should return a *new* instance of StringValidator.
```

The idea is that the ValidatorRepository should NOT know about the classes before these are added.This works fine, as long as I return the current object.

But instead I would like a *new* object of the class. I could to this by putting a static getInstance() function in each validator, or use eval in some way, but I hope there might be another, less ugly, way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do something this simple:

```
public function add( $key, iValidator $value ) {
    $this->validators[ $key ] = get_class( $value ); // this call can be moved to get() if you wish
}

public function get( $key ) {
    return new $this->validators[ $key ];
}
```

[get_class()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) takes namespaces into account, so if you use namespaces then it will still be fine.

---

A slightly more flexible approach might be this:

```
public function add( $key, iValidator $value ) {
    $this->validators[ $key ] = $value;
}

public function get( $key, $new = true ) {
    if ($new) {
        $class = get_class( $this->validators[ $key ] );
        $class = new $class;
    } else {
        $class = $this->validators[ $key ];
    }

    return $class;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should be using is instead either inheritance:

```
abstract class Validated {

    public function validate(){
        foreach(self::VALIDATIONS as $val) {
            // ...
        }
    } 
}

class Person extends Validated {

    protected $name;

    const VALIDATIONS = array(
       'name' => array( 'length' => new LengthValidator(15) )
    ); 
}
```

or traits:

```
trait Validated {
    function validate(){
        // ...
    }
}

class Person {
    use Validated;
}
```

Shoving all the validation logic into a single class violates the [single responsibly principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) since it becomes responsible for for validating all classes which use it. It will quickly get out of hand.

Note that I have used a constant for the validations - you rarely need to change validation rules for a class during runtime.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your great advice! I will definitely implement it this way later on, there is currently a very limited set of validators and things to be validated, but as you refer the singeltons are considered anti-pattern.